# Calculate Percentage when Button is Pressed Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-watch

I was wondering how I will be able to calculate percentage using Swift. I connected my Buttons to add, subtract, and multiply but I don't know how to code for percentage. I want the app to add the percentage when the 10%, 15%, or 18% is pressed. Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are u trying to find the percentage of a number?

Comment: yes the user types a number then when a percentage is tapped it adds to it. its a tip calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func calculateTip(cost: Double, rateOf rate: Double)->Double
{
    return (rate/100) * cost
}
```

`rate` is whatever percentage they want. So let's say I want to tip 10%. When the function is called, the 10 is converted to a decimal; `rate/100`, then multiplying with the item cost will give me the tip amount.

So `var grandTotal: Double = cost + calculateTip(cost: cost, rateOf: 10)`

Comment: @user3391014 You're welcome.. I've added a more generic answer to incorporate the cost as well..